# @scheduled jobs sometimes run sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, scheduler

I am working on a springboot project, I created a scheduler which has to run after every 10 mins, I have two pods running @shedlock is also implemented but it sometimes run sometimes doesn't run neither it throws any error, after sometime again it started executing.
Can anyone help on this

Comment: You say you have pods. Is your application running on Kubernetes? Why are you not using Cron Jobs? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: I faced similar issue, shedlock is not executing sometimes

Answer (score -1):

so the given information is not too much.
I can show you a working example in a distributed system, that I assume you have since you are mentioned pods that means your service is on Kubernetes.

---

application.yml/application.properties

```
your-app-config-root:
  scheduling:
    shedlock:
      min-time-lock-should-kept: ${SHEDLOCK_MIN_TIME_LOCK_KEPT:PT10S}
      max-time-lock-should-kept: ${SHEDLOCK_MAX_TIME_LOCK_KEPT:PT30S}
    alert-on-unfinished-cleanup-scheduler:
      enabled: ${ALERT_ON_UNFINISHED_CLEANUP_SCHEDULER_ENABLED:false}
      cron: ${ALERT_ON_UNFINISHED_CLEANUP_SCHEDULER_CRON:0 0 8,11,14 * * *} # by default every day at 8, 11, 14
      minutes-since-cleanup-job-unfinished: ${MINUTES_SINCE_CLEANUP_JOB_UNFINISHED:1440} # by default 24 hours
```

Configuration for Scheduler

```
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.LockProvider;
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateLockProvider;
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.annotation.EnableSchedulerLock;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import static net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.annotation.EnableSchedulerLock.InterceptMode.PROXY_METHOD;

/**
 * The defaultLockAtMostFor is the default value how long the lock should be kept in case the service which obtained the lock
 * died before releasing it.
 * This is just a fallback, under normal circumstances the lock is released as soon the tasks finishes.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(interceptMode = PROXY_METHOD,
                     defaultLockAtMostFor = "${your-app-config-root.scheduling.shedlock.max-time-lock-should-kept}",
                     defaultLockAtLeastFor = "${your-app-config-root.scheduling.shedlock.min-time-lock-should-kept}")
public class SchedulingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
    }
}
```

The Cron job itself

```
import io.your-app-config-root.platform.cleanup.CleanupService;
import io.your-app-config-root.platform.cleanup.metric.MetricService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.annotation.SchedulerLock;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static io.your-app-config-root.platform.cleanup.scheduler.AlertOnUnfinishedCleanupJob.ALERT_ON_UNFINISHED_CLEANUP_SCHEDULER_PROPERTIES;

/**
 * This scheduled job is responsible for alerting on unfinished cleanup jobs after 24 hour.
 * ShedLock included for making sure not running concurrent jobs on the same tasks at the same time.
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = ALERT_ON_UNFINISHED_CLEANUP_SCHEDULER_PROPERTIES + ".enabled", havingValue = "true")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AlertOnUnfinishedCleanupJob {

    public static final String ALERT_ON_UNFINISHED_CLEANUP_SCHEDULER_PROPERTIES = "your-app-config-root.scheduling.alert-on-unfinished-cleanup-scheduler";

    private final CleanupService cleanupService;
    private final MetricService metricService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${" + ALERT_ON_UNFINISHED_CLEANUP_SCHEDULER_PROPERTIES + ".cron}")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "alertOnUnfinishedCleanup")
    public void alertOnUnfinishedCleanup() {
        log.info("Alert on unfinished cleanup job has started.");

       // DO THINGS

    }

}
```

Notice that this cron job can be turned on or off via env var depending on your needs.

---

The sql that I used for db schema migration via flyway.

```
CREATE TABLE shedlock
(
    name                 varchar(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    lock_until           timestamp(3)       NOT NULL,
    locked_at            timestamp(3)       NOT NULL,
    locked_by            varchar(36)        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_schedlock_name PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

There are a plenty of online cron generator to help you to generate your cron expression.

You wrote you need to run your job every 10 min, so the right expression for it
`"*/10 * * * * *"`.

If you have any further questoin, please give more details. :)